# Remove everything after a certain word in OpenRefine

Tags: regex, openrefine

I'd like to remove everything after a certain word ("am") in a cell with OpenRefine.

My data:

> Workshop im Rahmen des Weiterbildungsprogramms am 02. November 2015
>
> Brainstorming am 09. November 2015 in Bremen
>
> Workshop "Auswählen und bewerten" am 17. November 2015 in Hamburg

Example for Regex: `[\n\r].*am\s*([^\n\r]*)`

See it in action here: http://rubular.com/r/bBlXOMoos1

That works. I'd like to have the following result.

> Workshop im Rahmen des Weiterbildungsprogramms
>
> Brainstorming
>
> Workshop "Auswählen und bewerten"

I tried: `value.replace(/[\n\r].*am\s*([^\n\r]*)/, '')`

The problem is not so much the regex, I could remove the "am" in a 2nd step, if necessary. But I can't get the regex to work in combination with value.replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this with `Python/Jython` ?

```
import re
return re.sub(r"am.+","", value)
```

I think the Python's regular expressions are often more consistent than those of GREL. But if you want to use GREL, does this not work?

```
value.replace(/\s+am.+/, '')
```

I feel you are mixing the syntax of `value.match()` (which requires you to match the whole string in a cell, then select the substring you want) and `value.replace()` (where you can only match the substring you need).

Comment: No : this answer made 15 hours ago works, and the accepted response too ;)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is pretty simple actually, your missing the `.` before your `*` to remove all the trailing stuff, right now your regex is saying 0 or more spaces are following the `am`, but you want it to clean off everything else after it...This works:

```
value.replace(/\sam.*/,'')
```

[image]